# Alternative for endless loop as listener

Tags: java, java-ee-6, ibm-midrange

Ok, maybe this is kind of a noob question on my part. But I want to ask about this. I have a Java web application that checks a DataQueue from a AS400 with an endless loop. If there's a message in the queue, it transfers it to an MQ, if not, just keeps checking.

At first this was a good idea, but seems that when I deploy this web app (ServletContextListener) in WAS and start it, I just can't stop it. Maybe because it's consumming the resources.

So maybe an endless loop isn't the answer. Do you know a way to constantly check for new messages on an AS400 DataQueue?

Comment: ScheduledTimers? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: Quartz Timer? http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/faq

Comment: The documentation for `DataQueue` has an interface for adding a listener to the queue, to wake up whenever something is written to the queue.  Have you tried using that?

Comment: @ns47731 & Nambari, the references to AS400 and the ibm-midrange tag indicate the platform involved, which is not your typical Windows/Linux environment, a different paradigm in many regards.  On IBM i, going into a timer wait state is time lost that could otherwise be spent in a data queue wait state.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need to constantly check or manually pause..

You can pass a timeout value to read() and your app/thread will wait that long for an entry before returning.  If you pass -1, it will wait forever...

From
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahh/dqconsumerexample.htm#dqconsumerexample

```
         // Read the first entry off the queue.  The timeout value is
         // set to -1 so this program will wait forever for an entry.
         System.out.println("*** Waiting for an entry for process ***");

         DataQueueEntry DQData = dq.read(-1);

         while (Continue)
         {

            // We just read an entry off the queue.  Put the data into
            // a record object so the program can access the fields of
            // the data by name.  The Record object will also convert
            // the data from server format to Java format.
            Record data = dataFormat.getNewRecord(DQData.getData());

            // Get two values out of the record and display them.
            Integer amountOrdered = (Integer) data.getField("QUANTITY");
            String  partOrdered   = (String)  data.getField("PART_NAME");

            System.out.println("Need " + amountOrdered + " of "
                               + partOrdered);
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("*** Waiting for an entry for process ***");

            // Wait for the next entry.
            DQData = dq.read(-1);
         }
```

Comment: This sounds certainly promising. I read about the waiting interval on DQ. The read is more stable than the while(true). Meaning, it won't be as heavy on performance?

Comment: Yes.  I don't know for sure, but off the top of my head, I'd guess that the read(-1) is making use of the addDataQueueListener() method of the com.ibm.as400.access.BaseDataQueue class.

Comment: Due to the nature of the OS, on IBM i (fka AS400) a job or thread in a wait state has essentially *NO* impact on performance.  It will not become active until the wait is satisfied or expires.  With the case of -1, it will not expire.  No loop is necessary, and no worrying about CPU.

Comment: Excelent. Now I was kind of worried about the while(Continue) there, it is a boolean, right? I assume a while(true) maybe? I'm asking because I tried here and the processes on WAS ended looping internally (even when I removed EAR) and had to restart server and kill processes on the AIX. So... will this be ok?

Answer (score 3):

The listener is probably using all of the CPU since it's looping as fast as possible. If you throttle it with Thread.sleep , even for a few ms it would help.

Regardless, in a Java EE environment, you're better off using a Message Driven Bean

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncgl.html#bncgq

Comment: Basically I wanted to deploy in WAS so I made an EJB Jar and put it into a web project. Then, I deployed this web project as an EAR on WAS. I use the listener because I want the code to execute automatically after I start the EAR. Do you mean that Message Driven Bean could also do the same thing by it's own as an EJB JAR?

Comment: But this is not a generic Java EE environment.  The question is tagged ibm-midrange platform, and the post refers to a platform specific class, AS400 DataQueue (com.ibm.as400.access.DataQueue).  This refers to an OS specific object.  Multitasking on this operating system is also different.  So in this case, it pays to understand the IBM i environment.

Comment: @Xanathos - yes, the container knows to forward messages to the MDB by calling its onMessage() method. Here's an example that may be relevant http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0504_barcia/0504_barcia.html

Comment: @WarrenT - I'm not familiar with AS400, but we use an MDB at my company to listen to MQ messages between an AIX box and an IBM Mainframe running Z/OS. MQ is, after all, an implementation of JMS.

Comment: IBM i (formerly OS/400) runs on IBM Power Systems or Pure Systems, and like z/OS, is designed for balancing a large variety and quantity of application workloads.  It is an object-based OS, and DataQueues are an OS level object, handled by the OS.  A job (or thread) can go into a variety of wait states, and will not receive CPU time until the wait is satisfied or expires.  The moment an entry arrives on the queue, a dataqueue wait ends & the thread becomes active.  If you wait on a timer, you cant process any arriving entry till that expires.  A waste for no point.

Comment: @WarrenT I understand now. So the application itself is running on AS400, rather than just listening to messages coming from that system. It makes sense then to use the proprietary libraries that IBM provides. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Yep, np.  (side note: the OS is proprietery, but the JT400 / [JTOpen](http://jt400.sourceforge.net) libaries are now [community](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/team.html) maintained with IBM's assistance.)

Comment: @phoenix, MQ (1993) has been around a lot longer than JMS (2001) or even Java (1995).

Comment: The data queue objects in IBM i have been around since 1982, with the introduction of the System/38, a system way ahead of it's time.

Comment: WarrenT, no, the application is running in an AIX server. It communicates with an AS400 server, retrieving data from a DataQueue on it (KeyedDataQueue) and sends the data to another AIX with a Websphere MQ manager. To one of its queues.

Answer (score 2):

The [DataQueue](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/DataQueue.html) [`read()`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/DataQueue.html#read%28%29) method supports [InterruptedException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html).

Here's an example to loop for messages using blocking with interrupt to handle a clean termination:

```
public class DataQueueMappingListener 
  implements ServletContextListener, Runnable {
    public static final int JOIN_TIMEOUT = 30000; // join timeout in millis
    private Thread mapper;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        mapper = new Thread(this);
        mapper.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        mapper.start();
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        mapper.interrupt();
        try {
            mapper.join(JOIN_TIMEOUT);
        } catch (InterruptException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        AS400 as400 = new AS400(...);
        DataQueue dq = new DataQueue(as400, ...);
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                DataQueueEntry dqe = dq.read();
                if (dqe != null) map(dqe);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
        as400.disconnectService(AS400.DATAQUEUE);
    }

    private void map(DataQueueEntry dqe) {
        // map to MQ here
    }
}
```

The full example is available as a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/jamesallman/9331089).

Comment: Thank you James, I was hoping you'd give us the right answer.

Comment: @Xanathos From my observations, James is one of the top experts here on running Java on this platform.  I'd try his solution first, any day of the week.

Comment: @JamesA, forgive me, but I see a loop that basically checks every second for data.  Seems like it'd use more resources.  Are we missing some code higher in the app where we'd instantiate and object of your DataQueueMappingListener class and pass it into the addDataQueueListener() method of the com.ibm.as400.access.BaseDataQueue?

Comment: @Charles I noticed the `read()` method can throw _InterruptedException_ and revised my answer to remove the polling. I don't think a DataQueueListener would be useful in this situation. See bug [#315](http://sourceforge.net/p/jt400/bugs/315/).